# How can I split a corrupt pdf file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I am trying to split a 'n' paged pdf file to 'n' number of pdf files containing 1 page each in ".net". For normal pdf files, PDFSharp is working fine but for corrupt file its showing errors listed down.

When I use Adobe Reader and 'Save As' the file, the new file is uncorrupted one. But I do not want to do it manually. I tried to open the pdf in Adobe reader using 'Process' but I can't save from there without manually saving it. If I use other DLLs the job gets done but it adds watermark.

Errors while opening the PDF Doc:

- "Invalid entry in XRef table, ID=9, Generation=0, Position=0, ID of referenced object=1, Generation of referenced object=0"
- {"Unexpected character '0xffff' in PDF stream. The file may be corrupted. If you think this is a bug in PDFsharp, please send us your PDF file."}
- Object already in use exception.

For handling corrupt files through process I tried this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = file;
p.Start();
p.Close();
corrupt = true;
inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Since you say "If I use other DLLs the job gets done" and that Adobe Reader handles it, are you sure the file is actually corrupt and not just that whatever library you're using to process it isn't too simple and doesn't understand all the nuances of the format?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with a corrupt file gracefully is no simple task. You need a deep understanding of the file format. Extensive examples of what could go wrong from other broken implementations. And a strategy to resume parsing for each type of error.

If there isn't a nice pdf library that already has these features, you aren't going to find one here.

Comment: Hi, I have checked various labraries, none worked.. So I am using another approach now, I am trying to open the file in Adobe Reader through "process" because Adobe reader can repair the corrupt file itself, but I need to SaveAs the file also from there at code level without manually saving it, is it possible in .net?

Comment: IMHO don't. Push back on your requirements and find a way to make it someone else's problem. The file is corrupt, don't agree to process it.

Comment: Just because Adobe can save a new file with no corruption errors, doesn't mean that the content is "correct" or meaningful. Something may have been lost, and you have no way to know if Adobe's interpretation of the file is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this error today.
although the pdf file can be opened and also read by other applications. pdfSharp was giving this error to me
"Invalid entry in XRef table ..."
if you're using .Net Core you can use PdfSharpCore library (version 1.3.7 above) and open the corrupted files in moderate mode

```cs
   PdfSharpCore.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(filePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import, PdfReadAccuracy.Moderate);
```

[source](https://www.api2pdf.com/resolved-pdfsharp-invalid-entry-in-xref-table/)